# Upload to Skip Web Server

Tags: indy, delphi-xe6

I'm trying to upload a JSON file to the SKIP (getskip.com) web server and I am getting socket error 10054. They are not very good at giving samples of how, since they think everyone is using cUrl, but we are still using Delphi XE6 with Indy.

Here is what they provided.

For Java using OK HTTP:

```java
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"path\"; filename=\"<<file_name>>\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.novadigm.ext\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\r\n\r\n[{\"file_key\": \"path\", \"store_id\"::<<store_id>>}]\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://upload.goskip.com:8080/v2/backoffice/files/pricebook?type=json")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW")
  .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <<api_user_token>>")
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .addHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0")
  .addHeader("Accept", "*/*")
  .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("Postman-Token", "de9932d2-bda0-4df6-8a9a-e2d4f74c2048,d59a9861-1a65-471a-8ada-6e025e985dca")
  .addHeader("Host", "upload.goskip.com:8080")
  .addHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate")
  .addHeader("content-length", "407")
  .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Java using Unirest:

```java
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("https://upload.goskip.com:8080/v2/backoffice/files/pricebook?type=json")
  .header("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW")
  .header("Authorization", "Bearer <<api_user_token>>")
  .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  .header("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0")
  .header("Accept", "*/*")
  .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
  .header("Postman-Token", "de9932d2-bda0-4df6-8a9a-e2d4f74c2048,d1ea454e-594c-4746-9de7-e813377ff095")
  .header("Host", "upload.goskip.com:8080")
  .header("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate")
  .header("content-length", "407")
  .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
  .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .body("------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"path\"; filename=\"<<file_name>>\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.novadigm.ext\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"\r\n\r\n[{\"file_key\": \"path\", \"store_id\":<<store_id>>}]\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--")
  .asString();
```

PHP using HttpRequest:

```php
<?php

$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://upload.goskip.com:8080/v2/backoffice/files/pricebook');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setQueryData(array(
  'type' => 'json'
));

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
  'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
  'content-length' => '407',
  'accept-encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
  'Host' => 'upload.goskip.com:8080',
  'Postman-Token' => 'de9932d2-bda0-4df6-8a9a-e2d4f74c2048,c7acbc0a-6450-43d1-b4ca-bc2a56cebc4e',
  'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
  'Accept' => '*/*',
  'User-Agent' => 'PostmanRuntime/7.13.0',
  'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization' => 'Bearer <<api_user_token>>',
  'content-type' => 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
));

$request->setBody('------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="path"; filename="<<file_name>>"
Content-Type: application/vnd.novadigm.ext


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

[{"file_key": "path", "store_id"::<<store_id>>}]
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--');

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

Here is what I tried in Indy. I pasted the JSON file in to a Memo on the Form:

```pascal
function TFormJsonWrite.HTTPPost: String;
var
  JsonToSend : TStringStream;
  Response: String;
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create;
  IdHTTP1.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';

  JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create(memolog.text, TEncoding.UTF8);
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentDisposition := 'form-data; name=[{"file_key":''' + memolog.text + ''', "store_id"::001}]------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--';
  IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';
  IdHTTP1.Request.Accept := '*/*';
  IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip,deflate';
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentLength := -1;
  IdHTTP1.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
  IdHTTP1.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';
  IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := false;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Host := 'upload.goskip.com:8080';
  IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
  IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer eyJhbGc.......................';
  IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Postman-Token'] := 'de9932d2-bda0-4df6-8a9a-e2d4f74c2048,d59a9861-1a65-471a-8ada-6e025e985dca';
  IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout := 50000;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2;
  Response := IdHTTP1.Post('https://upload.goskip.com:8080/v2/backoffice/files/pricebook?type=json', JsonToSend);
  HTTPPost := Response;
  JsonToSend.Free;
  IdHTTP1.Free;
end;
```

curl

```
Kim@KIMNEW MINGW64 ~
$ curl -F "file=@"C:/mydata/Items-114946.json -H "authorization:Bearer eyJ........................." https://upload.goskip.com:8080/v2/backoffice/files/pricebook?type=json&store_id=001
[1] 13296
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Kim@KIMNEW MINGW64 ~
100  951k  100    53  100  951k     53   968k  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  967k{"message":"#/data: null value where array expected"}
```

They updating all their endpoints this is the latest I got.

```
curl -X POST   'https://upload.goskip.com:8080/v2/backoffice/files/pricebook?type=json'   -H 'Authorization: Bearer <api_user_token>' -F path=@<path_to_first_file>   -F path1=@<path_to_second_file>   -F 'data=[{"file_key":"path","store_id":<store_id_for_first_file>},{"file_key":"path1","store_id":<store_id_for_second_file>}]'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Delphi code is all wrong.

You are setting the wrong `Content-Disposition` header to the wrong value.

You are posting the JSON data as-is without wrapping it inside of MIME at all.

DO NOT set the `TIdHTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding` property manually.  You are not  setting up the `TIdHTTP` to enable compression support, but you are giving the server permission to send compressed responses, which `TIdHTTP` will not be able to decompress for you.

The *correct* way to send a `multipart/form-data` request using `TIdHTTP` is to use the overloaded `Post()` method that takes a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` as input, like this:

```pascal
function TFormJsonWrite.HTTPPost: String;
var
  JsonToSend : String;
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  PostData: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  JsonToSend := '[{"file_key": "path", "store_id": <<store_id>>}]';

  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout := 50000;

    IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := false;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ...';
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Postman-Token'] := '...';

    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP1);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2;

    PostData := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      PostData.AddFormField('path', '', '', 'application/vnd.novadigm.ext').FileName := '<<file_name>>';
      PostData.AddFormField('data', JsonToSend, 'utf-8', 'application/json').ContentTransfer := '8bit';

      Result := IdHTTP1.Post('https://upload.goskip.com:8080/v2/backoffice/files/pricebook?type=json', PostData);
    finally
      PostData.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If, by chance, the server has issues with how `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` formats the MIME data (ie, if the server rejects the MIME `Content-Type` and/or `Content-Transfer-Encoding` headers that are generated by `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` for each MIME field, as it does not yet conform to [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578), which is used by HTML5), you can format the MIME data manually to match SKIP's examples exactly, like this:

```pascal
function TFormJsonWrite.HTTPPost: String;
var
  JsonToSend : String;
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  PostData: TStringStream;
begin
  JsonToSend := '[{"file_key": "path", "store_id": <<store_id>>}]';

  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout := 50000;

    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW';
    IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := false;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ...';
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Postman-Token'] := '...';

    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP1);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2;

    PostData := TStringStream.Create(
      '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' + EOL +
      'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="path"; filename="<<file_name>>"' + EOL +
      'Content-Type: application/vnd.novadigm.ext' + EOL +
      EOL +
      EOL +
      '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' + EOL +
      'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"' + EOL +
      EOL +
      JsonToSend + EOL +
      '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--',
      TEncoding.UTF8
    );
    try
      Result := IdHTTP1.Post('https://upload.goskip.com:8080/v2/backoffice/files/pricebook?type=json', PostData);
    finally
      PostData.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

**UPDATE**: based on the new curl commands you have provided, the original examples you showed do not match the commands.  Try something more like this instead:

```pascal
function TFormJsonWrite.HTTPPost: String;
var
  JsonToSend : String;
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  PostData: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
begin
  JsonToSend := '[{"file_key": "path", "store_id": <<store_id>>}]';

  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout := 50000;

    IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := false;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ...';
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Postman-Token'] := '...';

    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP1);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2;

    PostData := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      PostData.AddFile('path', '<<path_to_file>>').ContentTransfer := 'binary';
      PostData.AddFormField('data', JsonToSend, 'utf-8', 'application/json').ContentTransfer := '8bit';

      Result := IdHTTP1.Post('https://upload.goskip.com:8080/v2/backoffice/files/pricebook?type=json', PostData);
    finally
      PostData.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```pascal
function TFormJsonWrite.HTTPPost: String;
var
  JsonToSend : String;
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  PostData: TMemoryStream;
  FS: TIdReadFileExclusiveStream;
begin
  JsonToSend := '[{"file_key": "path", "store_id": <<store_id>>}]';

  IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout := 50000;

    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW';
    IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication := false;
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ...';
    IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Postman-Token'] := '...';

    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP1);
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
    IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL2;

    PostData := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      WriteStringToStream(PostData, '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' + EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(PostData, 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="path"; filename="<<file_name>>"' + EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(PostData, 'Content-Type: ' + GetMIMETypeFromFile('<<file_name>>') + EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(PostData, 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' + EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(PostData, EOL);

      FS := TIdReadFileExclusiveStream.Create('<<path_to_file>>', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
      try
        PostData.CopyFrom(FS, 0);
      finally
        FS.Free;
      end;

      WriteStringToStream(PostData, EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(PostData, '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' + EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(PostData, 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"' + EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(PostData, EOL);
      WriteStringToStream(PostData, JsonToSend + EOL, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
      WriteStringToStream(PostData, '------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--');

      PostData.Position := 0;

      Result := IdHTTP1.Post('https://upload.goskip.com:8080/v2/backoffice/files/pricebook?type=json', PostData);
    finally
      PostData.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy. I tried both. The first one gives me EidHTTPProtocolException with message 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden. The second one I assumed that the EOL was a string with EOL := '\r\n'. I see in the TStringStreamCreate have the filename="myjson.json", but I don't see how it get the content of the file into the TStringStream. I get an 500 Internal Server

Comment: I added the curl and it looks like it works except for the error about the json file which is 952K.

Comment: I added a new curl.

Comment: I just tested the new curl with Git Bash and it works, but I still get 403 using Delphi Indy. Any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: `EOL` is defined in Indy's `IdGlobal` unit. Yes, it is `\r\n`. The HTTP 403 error means your authentication is wrong, either becayse the OAuth token is stale or otherwise invalid, or maybe you missed a step in the authentication process, such requesting the OAuth token, or receiving cookies that need to be sent back, etc. As for the curl commands, I have updated my answer to reflect them. If you still get errors, then you need to capture the actual HTTP request(s) curl is sending, and compare them to the requests `TIdHTTP`'s is sending.

Comment: Thanks Remy the TIdMultipartFormDataStream works flawless. I appreciate you time to help me, second time you have saved me in the last month.